# How do I graph a vertical isocline?

Tags: plotting

The function r/a is a verticle isocline. I need to find a way to graph it. Right now the line is not showing, even when it equals y. I have experimented with Epilogue, but I am too unfamiliar with it to incorporate it with the stream plot.

------------------------HERE IS MY CODE-----------------------------------

```
    Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[{d/(f*a), r/a}, {x, 0, 100}, 
   PlotStyle -> {RandomChoice, Thick}, ImageSize -> Full, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}], 
  StreamPlot[{{(r*x - (a*x*y)), (f*a*x*y - d*y)}}, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0,
     100}], AxesLabel -> {"N", "P"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ContentSize -> {100, 100}],

 {{r, 25}, 0, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{N, 50}, 0, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a, .5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f, .5 }, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, .5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: I just don't understand your problem.

Comment: `a` and `f` cannot be allowed to be zero (division by zero). The lower limit for those controls should be a small positive number such as `10^-6`

Comment: Also, the `N` controller doesn't do anything in your code, but in general don't use `N` since it is a built-in symbol.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's the other isocline that needs to be vertical.  Setting the first equation ($dx/dt$) equal to zero, you get $y=r/a$ (or the trivial $x=0$).  Setting the second ($dy/dt$) equal to zero, you get $x=d/(fa)$.

You can't `Plot` a vertical line, since it isn't a function.  One dirty trick is to plot one with a very large slope instead.  For example,

```
Plot[{10^6*(x - d/(f*a)), r/a}, ...
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]